# java: how to execute some Runnables sequentiallly?

Tags: java, multithreading

while we want to execute 2 `Runnable`s :

```
executor.execute(new Runnable1());
executor.execute(new Runnable2());
```

it is unknown that which `Runnable` will start to be executed first? but I want Runnable1 be started for execution first. how to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not create one runnable which just runs `Runnable1()` then `Runnable2()`? If you don't want them to execute in parallel, don't submit them both to an executor separately...

For example:

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        new Runnable1().run();
        new Runnable2().run();
    }
});
```

Of course, you should consider what you want to happen if `Runnable1` throws an unchecked exception - do you want `Runnable2` to run or not?

EDIT: With your updated requirements, it sounds like *really* you want your second runnable to only start when your first runnable has reached a particular point (e.g. a socket has been created and is listening for connections). You quite possibly want to put some sort of hook in that code, so that you can start the second runnable *when you get there*:

```
// Somewhat pseudo-code...
Server server = new Server();
server.onStartedListening(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        executor.execute(new ClientConnection());
    }
});
executor.execute(server);
```

Comment: I want them to execute in parallel but first the one which i want starts(not finish execution, only start) then the other

Comment: @Soheil: That makes no sense. Imagine that either of them can be interrupted *immediately* after starting - before it executes the first statement. What's the difference between that and the "wrong" one starting first? It sounds like you need to clarify in your own mind what ordering requirements you have. Does the first runnable have to reach some specific stage before the second is allowed to start?

Comment: for example the first `Runnable` is a `ServerSocket` which must first start to be executed and waits for incoming connections, and the second one is the client (a `Socket`) that wants to connect to that server, so both concurrency and sequential are important

Comment: How do you prevent Runnable1 from "not finishing execution"? The OS can pre-empt your thread/process whenever it feels like it. You have no control over the OS Scheduler. This can never work unless you're specifically targeting your app to run on a multi-CPU non-pre-emptive multitasking OS (which I'm pretty sure doesn't actually exist).

Comment: @JonSkeet in the situation i mentioned above, the Server Runnable MUST to be executed FIRST, waits for incoming Sockets for accepting, then other `Runnable` which is the `Socket` that wants to connect start to be executed..

Comment: But more importantly, you've got to get to *one specific part* of the first `Runnable` - the socket has to have been created. It's no good *just* starting the first runnable first, if it doesn't reach that point before the second runnable starts.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, now we reach to the first question again, how to do run one first? on the other hand, I was thinking on Lock and Condition, what do you think?

Comment: @Soheil: No, the question isn't "how to do run one first" - it's "how to reach a specific point in one task before starting the next" which is very different. And no, I wouldn't introduce locks etc - I'd add a hook so that you can make it clear that you only want to start the second task when the first has reached the appropriate point. See my edited answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't understand your code, what is `.onStartedListening()` ? OK, we must run the other Runnable while the server is up and is waiting to accept incoming connections, but how to understand is server listening on it's port?

Comment: @Soheil: `onStartedListening()` would be a method you'd add to your server code, which allows a hook to be called when the port has been created. Fundamentally you *must* expose that aspect somehow.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please help me more on how to understand whether is the `serverSocket` listening on it's specified port or not? nothing came to my mind !

Comment: @Soheil: Um, you make the code which creates the socket notify the listeners when it's created the socket and started listening...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23567/discussion-between-soheil-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Runnable2() code check for status of `Runnable1.completed`

Where in Runnable1 define a `static boolean completed = false;` and make it true once the execution is finished in Runnable1